# Send email using Graph API only from few user accounts in background process

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-mail

I have a background application ( azure function ) which needs to send email from our service account to set of the users under same tenant . I am planning to use the GRAPH api to send the email and I can achieve it using below steps

a. Register an app in azure directory
b. Assign the application permission to send email as any user
c. Get the admin consent for that permission
d. write c# code to get the token and call graph api to send email

I do not see issue with the above approach except the fact that we will be getting the consent to send email as any user , which is quiet dangerous , this will enable me to send email as CEO or CFO of our company

could you please help or guide me if there is any way to send email on behalf of other user using graph api for demon applications ?

Regards,
Kumar

Answer (score 0):

You can scope the Service principal permission just to the mailboxes you need to send as https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-limit-mailbox-access. The other way is to have a service account and the grant it delegate access to mailboxes you want to send as but this is generally less secure and harder to maintain (eg you have username and password).

Comment: Thanks. Also, I would like to know if it is possible to get delegated permission for a user account and now in my background process, i will use the get the aad token for that user using username and password and send email?

Comment: You can use ROPC https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth-ropc but this isn't best practice.

Comment: Its quite the opposite. ROPC is not suggested unless you have a high trust on your application